# React Bootstrap Popover: Pre-Open Popover on initialization

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

How do I pre-open (initialize as open) a React Bootstrap Popover? I have the following which works in the initial closed state,

```
const popoverApproverNewAgreement = (
    <Popover id="popover-approverNewAgreement">
        <Popover.Title as="h3"></Popover.Title>
        <Popover.Content>
        Some text
        </Popover.Content>
    </Popover>
);

<OverlayTrigger trigger="click" rootClose placement="bottom" overlay={popoverApproverNewAgreement}>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" className="more-info">
        <i className="fas fa-question-circle" aria-label="more information">
        </i>
    </a>
</OverlayTrigger>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get it to work with `OverlayTrigger` but succeeded with the more generic `Overlay` which takes a `show={..}` so that you can show/hide with a state variable.

`Overlay` requires a `target ref` as below.

```
// Ref for Link or Button triggering overlay (required for <Overlay> usage)
const refLink = useRef(null); 

// State variable
const [overlayOpen, setOverlayOpen]  = useState(true); // Initially open

<a ref={refLink} href="javascript:void(0)" onClick={() => setOverlayOpen(!overlayOpen)}>
    <i className="fas fa-question-circle" aria-label="more information">
    </i>
</a>
<Overlay target={refLink.current} show={overlayOpen} 
         onHide={() => setOverlayOpen(false)} rootClose placement="bottom">
    {popoverApprover}
</Overlay>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking to the same problem and I've found that OverlayTrigger has a property called defaultShow (if you want a default behavior) and also a show property (that you can use to manipulate the component by a variable defined with useState, for instance).
You can find it here:
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/overlays/

**Edit**

The accepted answer works really well. But you will have to write again some ready-to-use code offered by OverlayTrigger - for instance it is really easy to handle an updating position dynamically with OverlayTrigger if that is your case of use.

Comment: Why not just use `Overlay` which should support this per the accepted answer?

Comment: I've just add new information about show property in OverlayTrigger and some considerations.